# What is the best practice for dealing with errors in a publisher in Combine? (Publishing heading updates from CoreLocation)

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, combine

I have been working on an app with a compass in it that updates its heading based on [this example](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UIKit-Combine/LocationHeadingProxy.swift) for publishing heading changes and [this example](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UIKit-Combine/HeadingViewController.swift) for creating a publisher to deal with those changes.

I'm very new to reactive programming, but the issue I'm running into seems like a common problem, so I wanted to post it and see if someone can help.

Sometimes it works for a little while, with new headings coming from the publisher and updating the UI, but then stops working. Other times, it doesn't ever start updating (an error is being delivered before any heading updates). In either case, it makes sense that the events would stop since a failure completion event is being sent to the publisher:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didFailWithError error: Error) {

    headingPublisher.send(completion: Subscribers.Completion.failure(error))

    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

First, I'm trying to figure out what these errors are so I can try to deal with them better... is the error really worth stopping the publisher? I am wondering what kind of error can happen mid-stream of heading updates, since heading updates resume after the error, even though the publisher stops. I tried printing the error, but all I get is this, which doesn't seem helpful:
`error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)`

I am not great at iOS, so if anyone has suggestions for how to get a better error description here please let me know.

Second, I'm wondering how I can ignore errors from the publisher on the subscription, if that's what I should be doing, so `.sink` will keep getting heading updates even after there is an error. Here's my publisher code below, based on the example:

```
    _ = headingProxy
        .publisher
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in },
              receiveValue: { [weak self] (heading) in
                self?.currentHeadingAccuracy = heading.headingAccuracy
                self?.currentHeading = heading.trueHeading
        })
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

I realize I could just not ever send the error to the publisher (is that what I should do? have a specific publisher just for the heading updates that never sends errors?) but I am assuming the person who made this included sending the error to the publisher with good reason, and that it may be a best practice to deal with it on the subscription side instead, or that there is some best-practice for recovering after an error.

Comment: The following might be helpful [Error Handling](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-general-error-handling) section from *Using Combine" book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, when an error occurs, that will always end a Combine pipeline built with off-the-shelf operators. This is a feature, not a bug. What can be especially surprising is that the pipeline will end even if you use an error-handling operator like `catch` or `replaceError`.

You can make a pipeline resilient to errors by wrapping any part of the pipeline where an error can occur in `flatMap`.

Think of your main pipeline as the "outer" pipeline and the pipeline(s) wrapped in `flatMap` as the "inner" pipeline(s). Make sure that the error type for the outer pipeline is `Never` and it can continue to process values forever.

Consider an endpoint that returns the square of a number:

```
let myNumberPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

// Outer pipeline will never error (the Error type is Never):
myNumberPublisher
  .map(String.init) // convert to string
  .flatMap { number in
    // Inner pipeline can error:
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://square?n=\(number)")!)
      .replaceError(with: "Oopsies")
      .map { answer in "The answer is \(answer)" }
  }
  .sink { result in print(result) }

myNumberPublisher.send("5")
// => The answer is 25
myNumberPublisher.send("3") // assume the endpoint errors here
// => The answer is Oopsies
myNumberPublisher.send("6")
// => The answer is 36
```

---

To use `flatMap` in your case, the class that vends the publisher could require that you ask for a new publisher any time an error occurs.

Alternatively, you could modify your `headingPublisher` to have a `Never` error type. If you go this route, errors should be handled by the object that vends the `headingPublisher`.

Another option is to vend two publishers, one for values and another for errors:

- `AnyPublisher<ValueType, Never>`
- `AnyPublisher<Error, Never>`

Any of these options can work and the one you chose will depend on your needs.

Comment: This is really helpful to get me on the right track, but I think I need to go learn a lot more right now and try to find some examples. I'm not really sure what you mean by with the inner and outer pipeline or how to use `flatMap` in this case without seeing an example. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "modify your `headingPublisher` to have a `Never` error type" so I will look into these things more and they help I'll be sure to come back to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's a difficult topic, and a difficult one to explain succinctly. I added a simple example to try to help with the explanation. If you look at the docs for the Combine built-in publishers you'll notice that some of them are described as "never failing". An example is the `Just` publisher. When you type-erase a non-failing publisher by calling `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` you'll see that the Type of that publisher will be `AnyPublisher<Never, Output>`.

Comment: "especially surprising is that the pipeline will end even if you use an error-handling operator like catch or replaceError" <-- so true!! a catch should catch, why does it end the publisher :((((( ??!